# Letters getting cut off from button when I make my window smaller

Tags: css, button

My letters from my button are getting cut off whenever I make my window smaller. I am not sure how to implement a solution. I have provided the css and the html. I also provided picture for better understanding. 
I know I have to change or add something in the css but I am not sure what.

I am not sure how to implement a solution. I have provided the css and the html. I also provided picture for better understanding.

[image]

```css
.button {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
// margin: 5px;
 padding: 0 22px;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
 height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
 line-height: 40px;
 background-color: #428bca;
 color: #FFF;
 font-weight: 600;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 border: none;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;

}
.panel-title {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-heading {

    color: #428bca;
    background-color: #428bca;
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
   border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;  
    //border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    //border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-body {
    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}
.nobottommargin {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}
.leftmargin-sm {
    margin-left: 30px !important;
}

.button.button-rounded {
 border-radius: 3px;
}

.button.button-reveal {
 padding: 0 28px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.button.button-large {
 padding: 0 26px;
 font-size: 16px;
 height: 46px;
 line-height: 46px;
}

.button-teal {
 background-color: #428bca;
}

/*code for the icon */
.button-reveal i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}
.button-reveal:hover i {
  left: 0;
}
/* code for the letters*/
.button-reveal span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
  transition: margin 0.35s ease;
}
.button-reveal:hover span {
  margin: 0 1em 0 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
        <h2 class="panel-title">Access This Service</h2>
       </div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <!-- angular -->
   
  <div ng-if="c.html" ng-bind-html="c.html"></div>

 <a href="http://zoom.us" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span>Go there now!</span></a><br>

Note: If you haven’t accessed Zoom before, create a new account at <a href="http://zoom.us">zoom.us</a>.
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The problem is the padding around the letters. I'm assuming when you make the window smaller the sidebar shrinks and so does the button. You could give it a min-width, as proposed by an answer, but that might prevent your sidebar from shrinking. You could also reduce the padding using `@media` to control button styles under a certain window width.

Comment: min-width messes with my button itself. How do I use @media?

Answer (score 2):

Just add `min-width` to your button and it will be fine

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  // margin: 5px;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #428bca;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-title {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.panel-heading {
  color: #428bca;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  //border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  //border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.nobottommargin {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.leftmargin-sm {
  margin-left: 30px !important;
}

.button.button-rounded {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button.button-reveal {
  padding: 0 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button.button-large {
  padding: 0 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}

.button-teal {
  background-color: #428bca;
}


/*code for the icon */

.button-reveal i {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}

.button-reveal:hover i {
  left: 0;
}


/* code for the letters*/

.button-reveal span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
  transition: margin 0.35s ease;
}

.button-reveal:hover span {
  margin: 0 1em 0 3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel-heading">
  <h2 class="panel-title">Access This Service</h2>
</div>

<div class="panel-body">
  <!-- angular -->

  <div ng-if="c.html" ng-bind-html="c.html"></div>

  <a href="http://zoom.us" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span>Go there now!</span></a><br> Note: If you haven’t accessed Zoom before, create a new account at <a href="http://zoom.us">zoom.us</a>.
</div>
```

Comment: I just tried that and It didn't work. If I change it to min-width i will mess with my button size if I make my windows smaller too.

Answer (score 0):

One possible route is to use **[@media query](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)** to control the button padding and other style attributes when the window is resized below a certain width.

Consider the following:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .button.test {
    padding: 0px;
  }
}
```

This says that if the window is below `800px` set `padding 0` on the element with `button` and `test` style classes. When the window is resized above `800px` wide, this selector is not applied.

The snippet below shows a button with and without application of @media query. I placed the query at the end of the stylesheet so padding is not overriden by other classes. You could also place it at the top of your file but then need to be careful so the cascading order doesn't override your styles.

View the snippet inline and then click on "full page" to see the padding change on the second button.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 22px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif, 'Lato';
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  background-color: #428bca;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  border: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.panel-heading {
  color: #428bca;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-left: 1px solid #dddddd;
  border-right: 1px solid #dddddd;
  //border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  //border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}

.panel-body {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.nobottommargin {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}

.leftmargin-sm {
  margin-left: 30px !important;
}

.button.button-rounded {
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.button.button-reveal {
  padding: 0 28px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button.button-large {
  padding: 0 26px;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 46px;
  line-height: 46px;
}

.button-teal {
  background-color: #428bca;
}


/*code for the icon */

.button-reveal i {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2em;
  height: 100%;
  line-height: 45px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  text-align: center;
  left: -100%;
  transition: left 0.25s ease;
}

.button-reveal:hover i {
  left: 0;
}


/* code for the letters*/

.button-reveal span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 2em;
  transition: margin 0.35s ease;
}

.button-reveal:hover span {
  margin: 0 1em 0 3em;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .button.test {
    padding: 0px !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Button NOT affected by @media</div>


<a href="http://zoom.us" class="button button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span>Go there now!</span></a>

<div style="margin-top:20px;">Button affected by @media</div>

<a href="http://zoom.us" class="button test button-rounded button-reveal button-large button-teal"><i class="fa fa-forward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   <span>Go there now!</span></a>
```

Comment: I just tried it but it didn't work. Look at the picture I just provided

Comment: Well, you do need to apply the example to your specific case. The media query does work - if you inspect the DOM you will see that the rule is applied when the window is `> 800px`. You can try to pinpoint at which width you see a problem on your page and apply a conditional style using @media query. You can change padding or even override all styles and generate a button that fits.

Comment: I tried using different px sizes but it doesn't seem to be working. :(